# Issue with CSS scale + position absolute

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a YouTube `iframe` with a `div` as a sibling.

I started from [this](http://jsbin.com/vunir/1/) and all works great. (the title is visible and the video is clickable).

The problems started when I had to add a css scale `transform` on the `stripWrapper` div: 
[example](http://jsbin.com/vunir/2/).

As you can see this caused my title to hidden behind the YouTube video. In order to fix this I [added](http://jsbin.com/vunir/8/) a `position: absolute;` on the wrapper `div`, which caused the title to be visible, but now the video is not clickable.

When I reduce the `z-index` of the `stripWrapper` the video is clickable but the title is not visible: [example](http://jsbin.com/vunir/5/)

Comments:
1. The 80% width is only because I want JSBin's "edit" button to be visible.
2. "stripWrapper" must be 100% height

Last test's code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="stripWrapper">
        <div class="strip">I am a title</div>
    </div>

    <iframe width="80%" height="100%" class="myIframe" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JTMf40ORFE8?playsinline=1&amp;controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.stripWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
}

.strip{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 12;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}

.myIframe{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

**edit**: All tests:

1. [test1](http://jsbin.com/vunir/1/) (everything is working, no scale)
2. [test2](http://jsbin.com/vunir/2/) (added scale - div is hidden)
3. [test3](http://jsbin.com/vunir/8/) (added position absolute - video not clickable)
4. [test4](http://jsbin.com/vunir/5/) (changed z-index - div hidden again)

Comment: What "-webkit-transform: scale(1.05);" using for?

Comment: Hey - this was only an example. I have to dynamically scale-up the content of this div

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You have tow divs, in the same size. Just one can be clickable. Am I missing something?

Comment: As I said, this is only an example of my case. I created it in order to visualise and simplify the problem. Indeed, I have two elements (div and an iFrame. The iFrame can be a div as well, it will still happen), and only one of them is clickable/visible (depending on the scenario/test I showed)

Comment: This is the natural behavior. It's just like in the real world - you can't click on any 2 elements with one hand at the same time. If one of them in the front, the other can't be clicked, even the first one is transparency.

Comment: The key issue is : Why do you want the wrapper to be 100% height ?

Comment: It is a wrapper which contains all page elements (except the youtube video). It must be full page

Answer (score 1):

Check it out just need to make sure you are scaling the iframe and make sure the container has position:relative;

http://jsbin.com/wiluyiwire